# Moq - how to access a class member when mocking?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

Assume this class:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Bar { get; set;}

   Foo()
   {
      this.Bar = "Hello world";
   }

   public void DoStuff()
   {
       this.Bar = "BAR" // imagine this is read from a memory stream
   }

}
```

I'd like to mock Foo and set it up so that I can introduce my own behaviour in DoStuff() - namely do some operations on the Bar member. But how can I access Bar on a callback from DoStuff() ?

What I tried: 
- Callbacks on DoStuff() don't seem to access the class state
- I could setup the Bar getter, but this is too general as other operations read Bar as well

Comment: What you're trying to achieve or what are you trying to test here? You need to explain that clearly in order to get good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't mock `Foo` for what you are doing. Mocks are used for providing tightly controlled concretions of dependencies within specific instances.

For example, if `Foo` had a member of type `IBaz` which was passed in the constructor, you could create a mock of `IBaz` where you tell `IBaz` how to react when `Foo` makes calls against its interface to trigger behaviour in `Foo` itself.